# Socket.IO server alternative in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, node.js, sockets

Actually I'm running a node.js application hosting a socket.io server and a restify.
Because the logic is getting more complex I want to shift this to an asp.net application. Restful services can be done via APS.NET WebAPI. How to integrate a new socket.io serer alternative that's compatible with the socket.io-clients?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr). I think this is what you are looking for. However it is a framework and not a server, so you need to host it on a server(works like a charm on Windows Server 2012). There is one little disadvante - it requires to be hosted on Windows Server 2012 in order to use websockets.

Comment: I know SignalR. But as my research showed me its different to socket io, so I will not be able to connect via the same code (socketio client) to a signalr server.

Thanks for the point regarding server version. Could be helpful